# ASP.NET Identity, reset password throws 'Name is already taken'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

I have a password reset action in my mvc controller with this code:

```
var user = AuthService.GetUser(command.IdUser);
if (user == null)
{
    return PartialView("_MessageFailed", "The user doesn't exists");
}
if (user.TenantId != command.IdWebsite)
{
    return PartialView("_MessageFailed", "You are not allowed to reset this user password");
}
var token = AuthService.GenerateUserPasswordToken(user.Id);
var result = AuthService.ResetPassword(user.Id, token, command.NewPassword);
if (result.Succeeded)
    return PartialView("_MessageSuccess", "The password has changed");
return PartialView("_MessageFailed", string.Join("<br>", result.Errors));
```

The user exists, but I'm having an error in the `result` object in reset method that says `Name user@domain.com is already taken.`

Why is this happening?
Could be because in the `aspnetusers` table in the database are two users with the same email and different tenantId? How can I fix this?

Update:
AuthService is a protected property like this:

```
protected AuthenticationLogic AuthService
{
   get
     {
       return authService ?? new AuthenticationLogic(HttpContext.GetOwinContext());
     }
            private set { authService = value; }
}
```

Where AuthenticationLogic constructor:

```
public AuthenticationLogic(IOwinContext owinContext) {
            this.owinContext = owinContext;
        }
```

Comment: What is `AuthService`?  Is that the ASPNet Identity thing, or your own wrapper around it?

Answer (score 3):

If the issue is a duplicate email address, you can disable the 'RequireUniqueEmail' property of the UserManager:

**C# Example**

```
manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
{
    RequireUniqueEmail = false
};
```

**Visual Basic example**

```
manager.UserValidator = New UserValidator(Of ApplicationUser, Integer)(manager) With {
          .RequireUniqueEmail = False
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The default UserValidator in ASP.NET Identity, does not allow for duplicates. You will need to provide your own implementation of `UserValidator<TUser,TKey>` (or `UserValidator<Tuser>`) and override the `Validate(TUser item)` method with your own implementation that also takes the TenantId into account

Then you will plug that `UserValidator` into the `UserManager`.